# Search between two date does not return last date informed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query that is not returning the last date informed, even though I put a smaller or equal operator. If I put the Start date greater than, it returns, but if I put less or equal, it does not return.

What would be the reason?

Period: **26-08-2021** to **25-09-2021**

```
WHERE B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO >= TO_DATE(:FRISTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')
AND B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO <= TO_DATE(:LASTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Using Only **Start date**

[image: Using Only Start date]

Using **Start** and **End dates**

[image: Using Start and End dates]

Comment: if your date does not specify the time, it will take 00:00:00 as time, so if you enter 25/09/2021 in your LASTDATE, then the 3 rows with that date will not show. Add time component, to it, or specify 26/05/2021 and use < instead of <= (this will insure that no data with 26/09/2021 00:00:00 will be returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the reason?

```
TO_DATE(:LASTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Will set the time component to the default value of midnight, so your query is looking for the bounds: `2021-08-26T00:00:00` to `2021-09-25T00:00:00`. Since, `2021-09-25T:05:04:50` is outside of that range it is excluded.

If you want the entire day then you have to specify a range that includes all the times of the day.

You could add a time component:

```sql
WHERE B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO >= TO_DATE(:FIRSTDATE || '000000', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
AND   B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO <= TO_DATE(:LASTDATE  || '235959', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
```

Or you could add a day and use the `<`operator:

```sql
WHERE B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO >= TO_DATE(:FIRSTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')
AND   B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO <  TO_DATE(:LASTDATE,  'DDMMYYYY') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment the problem is caused by the missing *time component* of the upper bound date.

The solution is to change the second predicate from

```
B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO <= TO_DATE(:LASTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY')
```

to (add one day and change the predicate to `<`)

```
B.PLOP_DT_FECHAMENTO < TO_DATE(:LASTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY') + 1
```